# Volume of a solid of revolution obtained by rotating: $y=\sqrt{x}$, $y=4$ on the axis $x=4$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

Determine the volume of a solid of revolution obtained by rotating: $y=\sqrt{x}$, $y=4$ around the axis $x=4$.

Well, I just determine the graphics and I'm stuck on how to proceed. This subject is new for me, but I already know how to solve so, the first analysis is my problem now.

Comment: What do you mean by "on the axis $x=4$ around $x$", specifically by the "around $x$" part?

Comment: is where supposed to rotate the solid

Comment: What are the bounds of the region? In terms of y?

Comment: The action of draw the graphics allow you to know the bounds.

Comment: Ok, so you did the graphics/plots. What did you get as bounds?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Ay%3Dx%5E1%2F2%2C%20y%3D4%2C%20x%3D4%2F%2F%5D

Comment: It's clear now?

Comment: Please, I need to solve this thing.

Answer (score 1):

Given an area bounded by $y = \sqrt{x}$, $y = 4$ and $x = 4$, the volume of the solid of revolution around $x = 4$ can be found with:

1. The [disc method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution#Disc_method) using the surface of discs with radius $y^2 - 4$ perpendicular to the axis of revolution between $y = 2$ and $y = 4$:

$$
V = \pi \int_2^4 \! (y^2-4)^2 \, \textrm{d}y \\
$$

2. The [cylinder method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution#Cylinder_method) using the surface of cylinders with radius $x - 4$ and height $4 - \sqrt{x}$ parallel to the axis of revolution between $x = 4$ and $x = 16$:

$$
V = 2 \pi \int_4^{16} \! (x - 4)(4 - \sqrt{x}) \, \textrm{d}x \\
$$

Try expanding both methods to make sure you get $\frac{1216\pi}{15}$.

Comment: Why is a (y2−4)2 un the first one?

Comment: Exactly, Why is there a (y^2-4)?

Comment: @Scoofjeer $y^2-4$ is the radius of the discs between the axis of revolution at $x = 4$ and the curve at $x = y^2$; $(y^2-4)^2$ is part of the calculation for the surface of a disc as in $\pi r^2$.